# Makefile only executes first target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When trying to execute the default target, only `setup` and the `o1` targets are executed. The remaining targets are not executed and I have no idea why.

Another potential clue: instead of make saying nothing needs to be done, make will always recompile.

Making the `o1` `o2` `o3` or `os` targets on their own will complete successfully if the directories are created.

```
# tail call test Makefile
# written by mwolf

SRC= tco recurs iter

OBJS= $(SRC:=.o)
ASMS= $(SRC:=.s)

SRC_DIR= src
OUT_DIRS= o1 o2 o3 os

CC=gcc

INCLUDE= -I.  
EXECUTABLE=

WARNINGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-align -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wwrite-strings \
    -Waggregate-return -Wcast-qual -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum  \
    -Wconversion -Wunreachable-code -Wformat=2 -Winit-self \
    -Wuninitialized -Werror-implicit-function-declaration


CFLAGS= -c -pedantic $(WARNINGS)
SFLAGS= -S -pedantic $(WARNINGS)

LIBS=

all: setup 
all: o1
all: o2
all: o3

setup: 
    mkdir -p $(OUT_DIRS)

o1: SFLAGS+= -O1
o1: OUT_DIR=o1
o1: $(ASMS)

o2: SFLAGS+= -O2
o2: OUT_DIR=o2
o2: $(ASMS)

o3: SFLATS+= -O3
o3: OUT_DIR=o3
o3: $(ASMS)

os: SFLAGS+= -Os
os: OUT_DIR=os
os: $(ASMS)

%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.s: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(SFLAGS) -S $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@

clean:
    rm -f *~
    rm -f $(ASMS)
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -rf $(OUT_DIRS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles give *make* a dependency graph.
Your makefile tells make that:

- `all` depends on `o1`

  - `o1` depends on `tco.s`, `recurs.s` and `iter.s`
- `all` also depends on `o2`

  - `o2` also depends on `tco.s`, `recurs.s` and `iter.s`
- etc.

Once *make* has built `tco.s`, `recurs.s` and `iter.s`,
then it has done all it needs to ensure that `o1`, `o2`, `o3` and `os` are up-to-date.

BTW you <strike>should</strike>must declare targets that do not correspond to real files as `.PHONY`